# Prove $\frac{Ax}{ \Vert Ax \Vert}$ is a contraction mapping

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I am going through a proof of the Perron-Frobenius theorem which uses the Banach fixed point theorem. The author first asks the reader to consider the space
$$
X = \left\{ x \in  \mathbb{R}^{d} : \Vert x\Vert^{2} = 1 \text{ and } x_{i} \geq 0 \right\}
$$

Then consider the matrix $A$ with strictly positive entries. We define the map:
$$
T(x) = \frac{Ax}{\Vert Ax \Vert}
$$
The authors then argue that, since T is a contraction mapping with respect to the geodesic sphere distance, the Banach fixed point Theorem can be applied. This results in a unique fixed point satisfying the conditions of the Theorem. That is, there exists only one eigenvector with strictly positive entries (Proving that the corresponding eigenvalue is maximal is done in the latter part of the proof).

I understand the overall idea of the proof but am struggling to work out **why $T$ is a contraction mapping.** The spherical distance is given by:
$$
d(x, y) = \cos^{-1}(x^{\top} y)
$$
Thus we need to prove that
$$
\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x^{\top}A^{T}Ay}{\Vert Ax\Vert \Vert Ay \Vert}\right) \leq k\cos^{-1}(x^\top y)
$$

for some $0 < k < 1$. One observation I tried using is that $\cos^{-1}$ monotonically decreasing on the domain $[-1, 1]$. Thus being able to show
$$
\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x^{\top}A^{T}Ay}{\Vert Ax\Vert \Vert Ay \Vert}\right) \leq \cos^{-1}(x^\top y)
$$

is equivalent to showing that
$$
\frac{x^{\top}A^{T}Ay}{\Vert Ax\Vert \Vert Ay \Vert} \geq x^\top y
$$
My plan was then to use basic facts about operator norms to prove this inequality but I couldn't make any progress.

EDIT: This question is based on the following [lecture notes](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Eknill/teaching/math19b_2011/handouts/lecture34.pdf).

Comment: Why not just restrict $T$ to the convex hull of $X$ and apply Brower fixed point theorem?

Comment: I guess this would work, though I am still curious as to why the aforementioned map $T$ is a contraction on the original space $X$.

Comment: Interesting question. All sources I know which prove Perron Frobenius via Banach's FPT use Hilbert's metric. The calculation there are quite laborious, so I think that there is no short proof using the geodesic sphere distance. However it would be nice to have a proof for this distance.

Comment: Yes, this proof seems very elegant if correct. However it seems that gerw has produced a nice counter example. I was beginning to think that an argument based on power iteration may be sufficient to prove the existence of a fixed point rather than BFPT. But I think this also runs into issues as one would need to assume the existence of a dominant eigenvalue.

Comment: Note that Brouwer's theorem doesn't give uniqueness, so it is only a part of the Perron-Frobenius theorem. By the way, one could also consider the simplex $S = \{x \ \text{s.t.}\  u^T x = 1, (x_i \ge 0)\}$ where $u = (1,\ldots,1)$ and define $f(x) = \frac{A x}{u^T A x}$.

Comment: Then you would apply Brouwer's theorem to the function $f$?

Comment: Yes, $f$ is clearly continuous and $S$ is convex and compact, so $f$ has a fixed point which is a eigenvector of $A$ with positive coordinates. There are other assertions in the Perron Frobenius theorem, so it is only a part of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a counterexample.
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
    1.00 &    0.01 &    0.01 \\
    0.01 &    1.00 &    0.01 \\
    0.01 &    0.01 &    0.01 \\
\end{pmatrix},
\quad x =
\begin{pmatrix}
    0.4748 \\
    0.0028 \\
    0.8801 \\
\end{pmatrix},
\quad y =
\begin{pmatrix}
    0.0028 \\
    0.4748 \\
    0.8801 \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then,
$$
\frac{x^\top A^\top A y}{\|Ax\|\,\|Ay\|} = 0.0683 < 0.7772 = x^\top y.
$$

Comment: Thank you! I was beginning to think there was a flaw in the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting,
\begin{align*}
(Ax)^\intercal(Ay) \ge (x^\intercal y)\|Ax\|\|Ay\|
\end{align*}
Note that, since all elements of $A$ are positive and elements of $x, y \in X$ are nonnegative, both sides of the equality are positive. Squaring retains the $\ge$ inequality, and using the fact that $\|x\|^2 = x^\intercal x$, we have
\begin{align*}
(x^\intercal A^\intercal A x)(y^\intercal A^\intercal A y) \ge (x^\intercal y)^2(x^\intercal A^\intercal A x)(y^\intercal A^\intercal A y)
\end{align*}
And again, because of the positivity (non-negativity) of the elements of $A$ ($x, y$, respectively), $x^\intercal A^\intercal A x$ and $y^\intercal A^\intercal A y$ are all $\ge 0$, so we can safely divide them from both sides to arrive at
\begin{align*}
1 \ge (x^\intercal y)^2
\end{align*}
which is true since $\|x\| = \|y\| = 1$ and Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: I see so the inequality follows from the fact that you can take the square root as everything is positive. I guess its not immediately obvious from this bound that $T$ is a contraction mapping as a constant $k$ may still not exist. But I assume there is a generalisation of BFPT which works regardless.

Comment: There is a mistake in squaring the left hand side. The third inequality implies the second, but the second does not imply the first.

Comment: Ah yes, you're correct. I am not really sure how to salvage the result given this.